# Merge based on partial string match in pandas dfs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this

```
first_name last_name
John       Doe
Kelly      Stevens
Dorey      Chang
```

and another that looks like this

```
name             email
John Doe         jdoe23@gmail.com
Kelly M Stevens  kelly.stevens@hotmail.com
D Chang          chang79@yahoo.com
```

To merge these 2 tables, such that the end result is

```
first_name last_name email
    John   Doe       jdoe23@gmail.com
    Kelly  Stevens   kelly.stevens@hotmail.com
    Dorey  Chang     chang79@yahoo.com
```

I can't merge on name, but all emails contain each persons last name even if the overall format is different. Is there a way to merge these using only a partial string match?

I've tried things like this with no success:

```
df1['email']= df2[df2['email'].str.contains(df['last_name'])==True]
```

Comment: What if two people have the same last name?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do with `merge` on the result of an extract:

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(last_name=df2['name'].str.extract(' (\w+)$'))
             .drop('name', axis=1),
          on='last_name',
          how='left')
```

Output:

```
  first_name last_name                      email
0       John       Doe           jdoe23@gmail.com
1      Kelly   Stevens  kelly.stevens@hotmail.com
2      Dorey     Chang          chang79@yahoo.com
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using only the last_name column from df1? df2 is generally messier and, while this merge mostly works there are some rows that don't due to hyphens, erroneous characters, etc.